# How to exclude transitive native libraries?

Tags: android, gradle, java-native-interface, android-gradle-plugin

Let's say my project is dependent on two libraries A and B. These libraries are dependent on the same version of a library C. Library C is dependent on a couple of shared library files D. To use library C, libraries A and B both include D in their jniLibs directories.

Now, the issue here is that when I attempt to build this project with the dependencies configured:

```
compile('group:A:1.0@aar')
compile('group:B:1.0@aar') {
    exclude group: 'group', module: 'C'
}
```

I receive an error stating that there are duplicate D files. How can I go about informing gradle to ignore certain jniLibs from only one of my libraries? Is there an exclude analog for jniLibs transitive dependencies?

Comment: "To use library C, libraries A and B both include D in their jniLibs directories" -- seriously? That's a bug in A and B. Neither need the native libraries in their own AARs. Do you control either A or B?

Comment: @CommonsWare I control library B. I could remove it but then other consumers of library B would be forced to provide the shared libraries or is there a way around this?

Comment: C should be an AAR, and C's AAR should contain the `.so` files. Is that the case? If so, then I don't see why either A or B need the `.so` files in their AARs. If C's AAR does not have the `.so` files, that's a problem with C. If C is not an AAR, then perhaps the answer is that you wrap C+D into an AAR and have A and B depend upon that AAR.

Comment: Ah ok great @Comm

Comment: Ah ok great @CommonsWare ! I don't believe that C is being packaged as an AAR and yes you are right, that is a problem with C (if that is the case). Nevertheless, I can, in the worst case, just wrap C+D into an AAR the both A and B can depend on. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to achieve this via gradle by forcing gradle to just use the first version of the shared library that it found:

```
android {
    packagingOptions {
        pickFirst 'lib/armeabi/D.so'
        pickFirst 'lib/x86_64/D.so'
        pickFirst 'lib/armeabi-v7a/D.so'
        pickFirst 'lib/x86/D.so'
        pickFirst 'lib/arm64-v8a/D.so'
    }
}
```